# How to get user id from IdentityServer in client app when including access token?

Tags: c#, identityserver3, openid-connect

I have implemented an authentication service based on IdentityServer3 and a simple MVC client app and a Shopper API secured by the authentication service. I've implemented a IdentityServer custom UserService so that the authentication service authenticates against our existing user data store. My Shopper API expects a userid in the Shopper Get request. Currently the response from authentication service includes the identity token and the access token, but no user id. I tried adding a user_id claim in the AuthenticationResult from my custom UserService.AuthenticateLocalAsync method, but I'm not seeing it in my client app code. 
UserService.AuthenticateLocalAsync looks like this:

```
try
{
    var user = new shopper(_dbConnLib, context.UserName, context.Password);
    var claims = new List<Claim> { new Claim("user_id", user.shopperid) };
    context.AuthenticateResult = new AuthenticateResult(user.shopperid, user.MemberDetail.billToAddress.FirstName, claims);
}
catch(shopperInitFromException ex)
{
    context.AuthenticateResult = null;  // Indicates username/password failure
}
return Task.FromResult(0);
```

And my client app SecurityTokenValidated handler looks like this:

```
SecurityTokenValidated = async n =>
{
    var nid = new ClaimsIdentity(
        n.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.AuthenticationType,
        Constants.ClaimTypes.GivenName,
        Constants.ClaimTypes.Role);

    var userInfoClient = new UserInfoClient(
        new Uri(n.Options.Authority + "/connect/userinfo").ToString());

    var userInfo = await userInfoClient.GetAsync(n.ProtocolMessage.AccessToken);
    userInfo.Claims.ToList().ForEach(ui => nid.AddClaim(new Claim(ui.Type, ui.Value)));

    nid.AddClaim(new Claim("id_token", n.ProtocolMessage.IdToken));

    nid.AddClaim(new Claim("access_token", n.ProtocolMessage.AccessToken));

    //nid.AddClaim(new Claim("user_id", n.ProtocolMessage.UserId));

    nid.AddClaim(new Claim("expires_at", DateTimeOffset.Now.AddSeconds(int.Parse(n.ProtocolMessage.ExpiresIn)).ToString()));

    n.AuthenticationTicket = new AuthenticationTicket(
        nid,
        n.AuthenticationTicket.Properties);
}
```

If I step through that in the debugger, userInfo.Claims always has a count of 0. How can I get back a claim with the unique identifier of the user? Or can I get it from the identity or access token? Or should I just pass the tokens to the Shopper API and let it determine the id from the tokens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I may have the answer. So far, as far as I can tell, the claims I include in the AuthenticateResult constructor in my override of AuthenticateLocalAsync don't seem to go anywhere. But the claims I include in my override of GetProfileDataAsync appear in the token. My GetProfileDataAsync code, which appears to set the claims properly, looks like this:

```
public override Task GetProfileDataAsync(ProfileDataRequestContext context)
{
    var user = new shopper(_dbConnLib, context.Subject.FindFirst("sub").Value);
    var claims = new List<Claim> { new Claim("sub", user.shopperid), new Claim("acr_level", "level 0"), new Claim("amr", "anonymous") };
    context.IssuedClaims = claims;
    return Task.FromResult(0);
}
```

My AuthenticateLocalAsync code that sets claims in the AuthenticateResult that I never see in my client app code looks like this:

```
public override Task AuthenticateLocalAsync(LocalAuthenticationContext context)
{
    // TODO: Handle AddshopperToBasketException in UserService.AuthenticateLocalAsync
    try
    {
        var user = new shopper(_dbConnLib, context.UserName, context.Password);
        var claims = new List<Claim> { new Claim("acr_level", "level 0"), new Claim("amr", "anonymous") };
        context.AuthenticateResult = new AuthenticateResult(user.shopperid, user.MemberDetail.billToAddress.FirstName, claims);
    }
    catch(shopperInitFromException ex)
    {
        context.AuthenticateResult = null;  // Indicates username/password failure
    }
    return Task.FromResult(0);
}
```